# I want to use multiple browsers using firefox on selenium but my speed is slowing down

Tags: selenium, firefox, proxy, slowdown

I have a project that I've been working on for a few days. I want to open multi browser using proxy. When I use Chromedriver it starts to close itself after 10 tabs. I don't experience shutdown in Firefox, but it loads very slowly even though my proxy speed is high. It says no internet most of the time.

Firefox Example :

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = {
'proxy': {
    'http': 'http://username:password@host:port',
    'https': 'https://username:password@host:port',
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your computer or internet cant handle it maybe be try outsourcing it to a platform like AWS EC2. This will run your script off of computers in the cloud so you don't have to worry about computing power or internet speed. There is a free tier that you can create multiple instances of if needed.

EC2 link: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/?ec2-whats-new.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&ec2-whats-new.sort-order=desc

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is not computer or internet related. My computer has 64gb ram and a 32 core processor. My internet speed is +100 Mbps. But I am still facing the shutdown problem. I consider this a problem with firefox. Thanks for your help though.